# Хочу сложить элементы массива, так , как это делалось бы в столбик на бумаге

Tags: c, массивы

Есть три массива : в первый ввожу число ,например, 12345, во второй ввожу число 22222 , соответственно в третий массив записываю результат сложения этих двух чисел, так , как будто бы это было посчитано на бумажке(ну сложение в столбик)
Вот код:(ошибка в нем есть, конечно же)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void) {
int A[5], B[5], C[10], i = 0, j = 0, k = 10;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    A[i] = getchar();
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    B[i] = getchar();
}
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = 4; j <= i; j--)
        C[k] = A[i] + B[j];
    k = k - 1;
}
for (i = 0; i<10-k; i++) {
    printf("%d", C[i]);
}

_getch();
}
```

Вот еще один вопрос: насколько целесообразно вводить посимвольно цифры числа через getchar() , просто иначе придется постоянно нажимать Enter после ввода каждой цифры.И можно ли хранить знак минус в интовом массиве ,

Comment: Для начала, обнулите массивы, вводите `... = getchar() - '0';` (получите бинарное представление *десятичных цифр*), обязательно проверяйте и если получили неправильное число, переходите к следующему шагу. А при сложении учитывайте перенос в старший разряд. И кстати,  вложенные циклы при сложении -- это ошибка.

Comment: @avp,а как тогда сложить без вложенного цикла?

Comment: Вы же складываете, а не умножаете, так что в одном, от младшей цифры к старшей. Только не забудьте, что длина результата может получиться на одну цифру больше, чем длины слагаемых